# How can I track a persons finger movement in android?

Tags: android, touch

I am trying to create an app that has you put your finger on a starting point ( an area with 150dpx150dp) and have it go through a specific pattern (like a maze).

How should I go about doing this? (I'm used to using the given buttons to do things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the [OnTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) Event to get the coordinates of the touch.

The event contains a instance of the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) class.

The process to move the object(eg current painting location) would be:

```
   b=get previous touch coordinates
   a=get cordinates of current touch  
   move object from location b to a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gesture - http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html